# How to read a cookie value in Jquery and create another cookie with same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, session-cookies, persistent

How do i get value of "id" from a session cookie "apple": Decoded below as

```
"{logo:"Y",id:"5555555555"}"
```

1. I want to get value of `id ="5555555555"` from `apple`
2. create another persistent cookie named `banana` and place this value "id" into it which expires in 10 days.

Pasted My code below:

```
Var res = $.cookie("apple");

<<Code to split it and get "id">>

$.cookie('id', 'the_value', { expires: 10});
```

I am new to Jquery and i am trying hard to get the basics . Please help!

Comment: Might help out with part of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-do-i-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery?rq=1

Comment: If the cookie is signed 'HttpOnly', you can't get it by javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Parse the JSON string in the cookie, then get the `id` property from it. You can then store this in the new cookie.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(res);
$.cookie('banana', obj.id, { expires: 10 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the usage section in the readme here: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#usage

---

> ### Usage
>
> Create session cookie:
>
> ```
> $.cookie('name', 'value');
> ```
>
> Create expiring cookie, 7 days from then:
>
> ```
> $.cookie('name', 'value', { expires: 7 });
> ```
>
> Create expiring cookie, valid across entire site:
>
> ```
> $.cookie('name', 'value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
> ```
>
> Read cookie:
>
> ```
> $.cookie('name'); // => "value"
> $.cookie('nothing'); // => undefined
> ```
>
> Read all available cookies:
>
> ```
> $.cookie(); // => { "name": "value" }
> ```
>
> Delete cookie:
>
> ```
> // Returns true when cookie was successfully deleted, otherwise false
> $.removeCookie('name'); // => true
> $.removeCookie('nothing'); // => false
>
> // Need to use the same attributes (path, domain) as what the cookie was written with
> $.cookie('name', 'value', { path: '/' });
> // This won't work!
> $.removeCookie('name'); // => false
> // This will work!
> $.removeCookie('name', { path: '/' }); // => true
> ```
>
> *Note: when deleting a cookie, you must pass the exact same path, domain and secure options that were used to set the cookie, unless
>   you're relying on the default options that is.*